# Error ORA-01017, Por DBLINK

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Cree el siguiente DBLINK,

```sql
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK ORA19 CONNECT TO USER_TEST IDENTIFIED BY "TEST" USING 'ORACLE19';
```

En el archivo TNSNAMES.ORA esta configurado así en el servidor.

```
ORACLE19 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = BDTEST)
    )
  )
```

Si hago una conexión directa con ese usuario por sqlplus puedo ingresar sin problemas, el problema esta cuando intento realizar una consulta por medio del dblink.

```sql
SELECT * FROM USER_TEST.TABLA@ORA19;
```

Sale el error:

```
ORA-01017: nombre de usuario/contraseña no válidos; conexión denegada
ORA-02063: line precediendo a ORA19
```

No se porque dice credenciales inválidas, las credenciales estan bien.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: intenta haciendo un `select count(*) from dual@ORA19;` adicional valida que el usuario tenga los permisos sobre dicha tabla!

Comment: Me arroja el mismo error ORA-01017, no entiendo el porque si las credenciales estan bien

Answer (score 0):

La contraseña se especifica sin comillas en la sentencia. A menos que las comillas formaran parte de la contraseña, lo cual no parece ser una buena idea, tu sentencia debiera lucir como esta:

```sql
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK ORA19 CONNECT TO USER_TEST IDENTIFIED BY TEST USING 'ORACLE19';
```

Comment: Ya lo intente sin comillas y me arroja el mismo error, las agregue para obligar a que tomara la contraseña en mayusculas.

Comment: has intentado establecer la contraseña en minúsculas para el usuario y configurarlo en minúsculas en el dblink? No lo digo como una solución final, pero al menos para arrojar algo de luz a dónde está el problema, descartando o confirmando si está en el CASE de la contraseña.